# FFMpeg: how to merge video and audio and tail align video to audio length?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have a video file and an audio file to merge together. Audio duration is shorter than video. I want to align them at tail and cut off the head part of the video.

Graph illustration:

```
[xxxx------] video
    [------] audio
    [======] merged
```

Where "x" parts of the video is removed.

The duration of the video/audio is unknown but the audio duration is guaranteed to be shorter than video. The reason of it being unknown is because I'm generating video dynamically and pipe to FFmpeg, so it is not possible to know the duration beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question since no one has answered yet, and I have found a solution after some researches.

My solution is to trim the video first and then merge the trimmed video and audio.

1. Get audio length
2. Tail trim the video and save as a temporary file
3. Merge the trimmed video and audio

```sh
    # get audio length
    AUDIO_LENGTH=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $AUDIO)
    AUDIO_LENGTH_INVERSE=$(echo "-$AUDIO_LENGTH" | bc)

    # trim video file so it matches audio file in length
    # -sseof $AUDIO_LENGTH_INVERSE: starts at audio length relative to EOF (end of file)
    # -i $VIDEO: input video path
    # -t $AUDIO_LENGTH: duration of the video that it should process
    ffmpeg -sseof $AUDIO_LENGTH_INVERSE -i $VIDEO -t $AUDIO_LENGTH $TEMP
    
    # merge video and audio
    ffmpeg -i $TEMP -i $AUDIO -c:v copy $OUTPUT
```